# To check if the array elements are continuous

Tags: arrays, perl

I have the following array

```
@array = qw(1 2 3 3A 3B 4 6)
```

and I would to like to check if the elements in my array are continuous

I have different scenarios of being continuous.

**Case 1:**  1,2,3,4 are considered continuous;

**Case 2:** 14A,14B,14C,14D should be considered as continuous;

**Case 3:** 1,2,3,3A,3B,4,5 should also be considered continuous.

*My window to check the continuity is two and whenever there is a discontinuity, I wish to return an asterisk (*) in its place, i.e. considering @array it should return * in between 4 and 6, since 5 is missing, hence returning 1 2 3 3A 3B 4 * 6.*

While the following code works when my array elements are similar to **case 1** but since @array has elements as in **case 3** my condition does not work and I seek an efficient way to tackle this, i.e.  *to cover all three case* .

```
for ($i=0;$i<=$#array;$i+=2)
{
    if($array[$i+1] == $array[$i]+1)
    {
        print $array[$i],$array[$i+1];
    }
    else
    {
        print $array[$i],"*";
    }
}
```

**Things to consider:**

- The array elements will always be numbers (e.g. 1,2,3) and numbers concatenated with letters (e.g. 2A).
- Need multiple asterisk for multiple missing elements, i.e. the number of asterisk should match the number of missing elements.

Comment: Do the letters have to be in order to be considered continuous? E.g. 3A,3C,3B would not? Are your 'things' always number + letter?

Comment: Would `3B`->`4B` be considered 'continuous'?

Comment: And - do you need to put in multiple stars if there's a larger gap than one?

Comment: @Sobrique 1) Yes, the letters should be in order. My element will always contain a number or "number+letter". 2) Yes, 3B -> 4B would be considered continuous. 3) Yes, need multiple stars for larger gaps.

Comment: `return true` fulfills all three criterions. Perhaps you should try to describe what is *not* considered continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a lot of things to solve your problem :

- split the letters from the numbers, using a regexp for instance,
- use `ord` to compare the letters
- and then, write the correct tests.

For instance, this code should do the job :

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @array = qw(1 2 3 3A 3B 4 6);

$\ = ' '; # adds a space after each print
for my $i (0 .. $#array-1) {
    print $array[$i];
    my ($nb1, $letter1) = $array[$i] =~ /(\d+)([A-Z]*)/;
    my ($nb2, $letter2) = $array[$i+1] =~ /(\d+)([A-Z]*)/;
    if ($nb2 == $nb1 + 1) {
        next;
    } elsif ($nb2 > $nb1 + 1) {
        print '*' for $nb1 .. $nb2 - 2;
    } else {
        if (! $letter1) {
            unless ($letter2 && $letter2 eq 'A') {
                print '*';
            }
        } else {
            unless (ord($letter2) == ord($letter1) + 1) {
                print '*' for ord($letter1) .. ord($letter2) - 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
print $array[-1]
```

Will print :
`1 2 3 3A 3B 4 * 6`

Comment: Needs multiple `*` for larger delta.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't saw his comment. I added the `for 1 .. $nb2 - $nb1 -1`, it should be better now.

Comment: @Dada Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand the purpose of line 16,  i.e.     unless ($letter2 && $letter2 eq 'A'). Why is $letter2 twice checked?

Comment: @Daddy_enakku_oru_doubt it was meant to check if `$letter2` is defined before comparing it with 'A'. `unless (defined($letter2) && $letter2 eq 'A'` might have been clearer.